# Simultaneous equations - Two equations, Three unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I feel stupid asking this but I'm stuck I have three unknowns (x,y and z) and two equations (300-y=z and x-100=z) and while I know how to find thee unknowns with three equations, I'm just hitting a wall here - My immediate thought was to get a third equation from the other two just the logic seems to be circular and I'm going nowhere - can someone help please?

Comment: Just choose $z$ as you please, and deduce $x$ and $y$ in function of $z$. The set of solutions is an affine subspace of dimension $1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of solutions.
See the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).
As others mentioned, the solution space forms "an affine subspace of dimension 1", also called a line ;)

This means you have some freedom. So just set $z=c$.

Then the solution is:
$$
x = c + 100
$$
$$
y = 300 - c
$$
which will be true for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$ that you pick.
(Going over all the values of $c$ will then form a line in 3D).

Comment: Sorry if this seems elementary, but what's achieved by setting z = c? are you not just substitution on unknown for another?

Comment: @Jeremy the point is that you *choose* $c$. E.g. Let $c=300$. Then one solution point is $(400, 0, 300)$. Notice that $300-0=300$ (which is eq. 1) and $400-100=300$ (which is eq. 2), so it satisfies the target equations. Now try $c=0$: you get $(100,300,0)$, which also satisfies the initial equations.The point is that $c$ can be *anything*.  Mathematically, it is *impossible* to have a single unique solution when there are more equations that unknowns. That's what the theorem I linked says. So you have infinite solutions (a line in 3-space).